# How to use like in an in sql statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-like

Hi I'm using PHP to try and retrieve data from a database while looping through an array inside the in statement like this.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pixacour_pixacourt.UserCaseMessages WHERE FavorIDs IN  (" ;
    $count = 0;
foreach($followingArray as $value)
{
    if($count==count($followingArray)-1)
    {
        $sql2 .= "LIKE";
        $sql2 .= "%'".$value."'%";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql2 .= "LIKE";
        $sql2 .= "%'".$value."'%,";        
    }
    ++$count;
}
$sql2 .= ")";
```

I get this error, that says

> "trying to get property of non object"

I can't figure out what is going on any suggestions would be much appreciated thank you for your time.

Comment: Print out the `$sql2` and then include it in the message.  The problem will probably be obvious.  For instance, `like` doesn't go in the list of values used by `IN`.

Comment: I would suggest asking another question with sample data and desired results, and explaining what you are trying to do.  I would suggest modifying this question, but it now has an answer, and your changes could possible invalidate the answer -- which is rude.

Comment: "Trying to get property of non object" means the SQL query function is returning `false` because of a syntax error. Which means you're using the result without checking for errors. Why wouldn't you do basic debugging like that before posting to SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using LIKE in an IN clause but you do need to comma delimit elements.  No need to keep track of the count, either.  foreach will cease when the array has been traversed and you can trim off the trailing comma.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pixacour_pixacourt.UserCaseMessages WHERE FavorIDs IN  (" ;
foreach($followingArray as $value)
{
        $sql2 .= "'".$value."', ";        
}
$sql2 = rtrim($sql2,',');
$sql2 .= ");";
```

If this fails, like Gordon says, echo $sql2 and the syntax error will probably be clear.

If you do indeed need to use LIKE and wildcard matching, you could append multiple OR clauses, one for each $value.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pixacour_pixacourt.UserCaseMessages WHERE " ;
$whereClause = "";
foreach($followingArray as $value)
{
        $whereClause .= " OR FavorIDs LIKE '%".$value."%' ";        
}
$whereClause = ltrim($whereClause, " OR");
$sql2 .= $whereClause . ";";
```

**UPDATE 1/9/15**

I realized there's a bug in this code in that when $followingArray is empty, we'd receive a MySQL syntax error because the query ends with "WHERE".  Here's a new version which resolves that bug:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pixacour_pixacourt.UserCaseMessages" ;
if(count($followingArray) >= 1) {
    $sql2 .= " WHERE";
}
$whereClause = "";
foreach($followingArray as $value)
{
        $whereClause .= " OR FavorIDs LIKE '%".$value."%' ";        
}
$whereClause = ltrim($whereClause, " OR");
$sql2 .= $whereClause . ";";
```

Comment: Thank you all this was very helpful:)

Comment: Happy to help! Best of luck.